# C Floating Point exception (core dumped)

Tags: c, runtime-error

I am a noob studying C and have tried to create a program that provides the highest common divisor of 2 entered numbers. However, after a successful compile, I get the titled error after I enter data to the scanf prompt. I have tried for ever to solve it but cannot. Please ignore the double slashes.

```
//Declare external libraries and function calls //
#include <stdio.h>
void gcdFunction (int *variable1, int *variable2);

// Main Program//
int main(void)
{
    int firstNumber = 0, secondNumber = 0;
    printf("Please enter first value \n");
    scanf("%d", &firstNumber);
    printf("Please enter second value \n");
    scanf("%d", &secondNumber);
//Call function passing 2 address parameters //
    gcdFunction(&firstNumber, &secondNumber);
}

// Call function, passing parameters as pointers //
void gcdFunction(int *variable1, int *variable2)
{
    int i, z;
    while (i != 0)
    {
        i = *variable2;
        *variable2 = *variable1 % *variable2;
        *variable1 = i;
    }
    z = *variable1;
    printf("\nThe GCD of the two values entered is: %d", z);
}
```

Comment: Did you mean to tag C# instead of C?

Comment: Yes, I am a noob.

Comment: `i` is uninitialized....

Comment: You should loop `while (*variable2 != 0)`, not `while (i != 0)`. Alternatively, you can set `i = *variable2` before you enter the loop, and set it again at the end of each iteration instead of at the beginning of each iteration.

Comment: What input values cause this to core on you?

Comment: Another alternative, is to simply change your `while` loop to a `do/while` loop (with the exact same condition). Assuming that you always pass nonzero value as the second input argument, it should work fine.

Comment: @barakmanos No, your last suggestion would suffer from the same problem.

Comment: @Ctx: Why is that? You place a `do` instead of that `while`, and move that `while` to the bottom. `i` will be initialized before being used.

Comment: @barakmanos *variable2 becomes zero, i is checked for zero in the loop condition and then *variable2 is used in the next iteration. This is independent from if the loop condition is checked at the beginning or the end of the loop. It only fixes the "uninitialized"-problem, but not the FPE

Comment: @Ctx: Oh yeah, that's right. Good thing I didn't put that in the answer...

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in this loop:

```
while (i !=0){
    i = *variable2;
    *variable2 = *variable1 % *variable2;
    *variable1 = i;
}
```

Here, if `*variable2` becomes 0 it is used as the modulo right-hand-side in the next iteration, since `i` is set *after* checking the loop condition. Change it to

```
while (*variable2 !=0){
    i = *variable2;
    *variable2 = *variable1 % *variable2;
    *variable1 = i;
}
```

then the error should no longer occur.

Comment: I thank you sir for your help. I had been stressing this problem for hours, even with help and the internet.

Answer (score 2):

The following piece of code:

```
int i;
while (i != 0)
{
    i = *variable2;
    *variable2 = *variable1 % *variable2;
    *variable1 = i;
}
```

Embeds two problems:

- `i` is not initialized before being used at `while (i != 0)`
- `*variable2` may be zero when calculating `*variable1 % *variable2`

The first problem yields undefined behavior of your program.

The second problem may lead to a divide-by-zero exception.